# Matplotlib, avoiding unwanted triangles in plot_trisurf()

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have the following code to create a cone for which a displacement field will be applied later on. In the figure shown below you can see that some big triangles are drawn at the top, but not at the bottom. I believe there is some internal hidden parameter that tells `plot_trisurf()` up to which distance the triangles should be created, otherwise they should have been created at the bottom too.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
from numpy import linspace, interp, meshgrid, sin, cos, pi
numel_circum = 120
L = 38.
rb, rt = (38., 16.)
t1, t2 = (0, 2*pi)
rav = ( rb - rt )*rt/rb + rt
perav = (t2-t1) * rav
elsize_L = perav / numel_circum
numel_L = int(round(L/elsize_L,0))
ts = linspace(t1, t2, numel_circum)
r = lambda z: interp( z, [0, L], [rb, rt] )
zs = linspace(0, L, numel_L)
ts, zs = meshgrid( ts, zs )
ys = r(zs)*sin(ts)
xs = r(zs)*cos(ts)
# plotting
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(xs.flatten(), ys.flatten(), zs.flatten(),
                cmap=cm.jet, linewidth=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have probably moved on or solved this yourself by now, but I thought I'd throw an answer up for future vistors.

The reason you are getting triangles in the smaller circle is not a max-distance thing, it is because those triangles are contained within the convex hull of your points projection on the x,y plane.

If you look at the `plot_trisurf` source, (`numpy.source(Axes3D.plot_trisurf)`) you'll see that it performs delaunay triangulation every time and there is no opportunity to define your triangles or exclude unwanted triangles.

Two options:

#### the right way #1

copy the source of [`plot_trisurf`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/dffac7a59d6ffdaeb241f61c5178f56ad6f2b0b9/lib/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/axes3d.py#L1762) to your script and add the line [`tri.set_mask(...)`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/tri/triangulation.py#L189) (tri is a `matplotlib.tri.triangulation.Triangulation` instance) using the algo of your choice (some max edge length criteria or find triangles who centroids are within some radius.. whatever suits your actual data) to create the boolean mask after triangulation is done.

#### the right way #2

define the triangles without using delaunay triangluation using `Triangulation(x,y,triangles=...)`

#### the quick way

set plot_trisurf `vmax` to be slightly below the plane of the circle.

*I didn't try either of these options

Comment: I tried to play with the `vamx` parameter without success, and could you go just a little further into details with "the right way" solution?

Comment: @SaulloCastro  I added some links and expanded a bit.  Not sure where to elaborate.  You understand how set_mask works?  Is this a toy example?  Do you need a general solution or a solution for your specific problem?

Comment: the example is an extreme case of a real problem, where we have cones with different geometries (and also cylinders). Solving this extreme case will solve the others, which are more cylinder-like... thank you for the update... I will take a look...