# Plot a 3D surface from {x,y,z}-scatter data

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-3d

I'm trying to plot a 3D surface constructed to fit some {x,y,z} points in python -- ideally something like the Mathematica [`ListSurfacePlot3D`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListSurfacePlot3D.html) function. Thus far I've tried `plot_surface` and `plot_wireframe` on my points to no avail.

Only the axes render with `plot_surface`. `plot_wireframe` gives a bunch of squigglys, vaguely in the shape of the object, but not the nice sort that is shown in the documentation:
[image]
Compare to the result from `ListSurfacePlot3D`:
[image]

Here is a minimal working example, using a test.csv file I posted [here](http://pastebin.com/0B1z2SBv):

```
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot
import pylab
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

hFile = open("test.csv", 'r')
datfile = csv.reader(hFile)
dat = []

for row in datfile:
        dat.append(map(float,row))

temp = zip(*(dat))

fig = pylab.figure(figsize=pyplot.figaspect(.96))
ax = Axes3D(fig)
```

Then, either

```
ax.plot_surface(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2])
pyplot.show()
```

or

```
ax.plot_wireframe(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2])
pyplot.show()
```

This is how it renders using `plot_surface`:
[image]
and using `plot_wireframe`:
[image]
and using `ListSurfacePlot3D`:
[image]

Comment: what exactly is the problem you're having with `plot_surface` and `plot_wireframe`?

Comment: @ali_m just the axes render with `plot_surface` (and I get a undescriptive Visual C++ runtime error). `plot_wireframe` gives a bunch of squigglys, vaguely in the shape of the object, but not the nice sort that is shown in the documentation.

Comment: @Marcin It's difficult to get a MWE, since I can't share the dataset I'm trying to plot, sorry. I _can_ plot the points using `scatter`, so I'm pretty sure I have the other stuff set up correctly.

Comment: Could you create some dummy data in the same format? Or at least show the code?

Comment: @Marcin I'm trying to see if I can generate some data which I can share / code which is meaningful.

Comment: You'll likely find that helps shake out some of your confusion.

Comment: I've updated the question with some more info

Comment: Could you give the runtime error that you get with `plot_surface`?

Comment: @ali_m Interesting. Turns out, the run time error (http://i.imgur.com/p4Qtb3P.png) turns up for either plot, if I didn't close a previous plot window that was already open. With that closed, neither gives that error.

Comment: OK, so does `plot_surface` work for you if you close the previous window?

Comment: @ali_m no, it just displays an empty set of axes

Comment: Can you plot anything at all using plot_surface? For example: `ax = axes(projection='3d');u, v = np.mgrid[0:2*np.pi:20j, 0:np.pi:10j];
x=np.cos(u)*np.sin(v);
y=np.sin(u)*np.sin(v);
z=np.cos(v);
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=1,cstride=1)`

Comment: @ali_m As in the example [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_examples/mplot3d/surface3d_demo2.py) -- yes.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32581/discussion-between-ali-m-and-eli-lansey)

Comment: @Marcin I've managed to put together a mwe. See updated question.

Comment: Your axes for the `plot_surface` look at a glance rather different from the other plots. Maybe you're basically zoomed in on an empty bit of the plot space?

Comment: @Marcin They're just rotated -- the scale is the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`plot_surface` expects X,Y,Z values in the form of 2D arrays, as would be returned by `np.meshgrid`. When the inputs are regularly gridded in this way, the plot function implicitly knows which vertices in the surface are adjacent to one another and therefore should be joined with edges. In your example, however, you're handing it 1D vectors of coordinates, so the plotting function would need to be able to figure out which vertices should be joined.

The `plot_trisurf` function does handle irregularly spaced points by doing a Delaunay triangulation to determine which points should be joined with edges in such a way as to avoid 'thin triangles':

[image]

Comment: Nice! That's exactly what I was looking for. Is there a way to adjust the density of the triangulation? Or do I need to manually thin out my dataset?

Comment: @EliLansey see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16300809/matplotlib-avoiding-unwanted-triangles-in-plot-trisurf)

Comment: This does a decent job on my actual dataset, but still has some issues, see: http://i.stack.imgur.com/hcRbX.png Any tips?

Comment: Actually, it seems to be over-complicating things. I went to a larger dataset, and it's drawing connections all over the place (imagine a ball, but instead of being a sphere, it was chopped up, with triangles cutting from the top hemisphere to the bottom hemisphere).

Comment: Where do your x,y,z points come from? If you are generating them by some function `z = f(x,y)`, you could modify `f` so that it would accept 2D arrays of x,y coordinates. Alternatively you could try to resample your data on a regular grid, for example using [`scipy.interpolate.griddata`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.griddata.html#scipy.interpolate.griddata). Once you have your x,y,z values in a set of regular 2D arrays you can just use `plot_surface`.

Comment: They come from an external source -- there isn't a functional form for them. I may try monkeying with the internals of `plot_trisurf` and `tri.setmask` to improve this. Based on that answer you shared in the comment, "it is because those triangles are contained within the convex hull of your points projection on the x,y plane." -- I need to change that.

Comment: Yes, and my suggestion to interpolate would of course only work provided your data lie on a convex surface. I could imagine using `matplotlib.delaunay` to get a set of vertices for the `triangles=` parameter of a `matplotlib.tri.triangulation.Triangulation` instance, then applying a maximum edge length criterion to set the `mask=` parameter.