# How to plot 3D surfaces in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, geometry-surface

What should I change / add in any of the examples [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/mplot3d/surface3d_radial_demo.html) and [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#surface-plots) in order to generate a 3D surface from the following data?

```
[100, 0, 'TF', 0]
[100, 0, 'DF', 0]
[100, 50, 'TF', 0]
[100, 50, 'DF', 0]
[100, 100, 'TF', 0]
[100, 100, 'DF', 0]
[100, 150, 'TF', 0.84496124031007758]
[100, 150, 'DF', 0.87209302325581395]
[100, 200, 'TF', 0.88139534883720927]
[100, 200, 'DF', 0.86201550387596892]
[100, 250, 'TF', 0.87441860465116272]
[100, 250, 'DF', 0.889922480620155]
[100, 300, 'TF', 0.87984496124031009]
[100, 300, 'DF', 0.89922480620155043]
[100, 350, 'TF', 0.92015503875968996]
[100, 350, 'DF', 0.90697674418604657]
```

NOTE: I do have tried a few things based on the code mentioned above, but I didn't manage to make it work so far. The reason I didn't quote my code here it is because I would make my question must more complicated that it actually is.

Comment: I thin the relavent line in the first example is ```ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.YlGnBu_r)```.  You need to extract the x, y, and z data from your lists and use that data as the X, Y, and Z arguments to that function.  Pretty sure those can be lists as well as numpy arrays.

Comment: `plot_surface()` requires your X,Y and Z data to be regularly gridded in 2D arrays, such as you'd get from `np.meshgrid()`. It's not totally clear how your data is structured (what are `'TF'` and `'DF'`?), but it looks like it is not regularly gridded. You could try `plot_trisurf()`, which will accept irregular X,Y,Z data in the form of 1D arrays - [see my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367558/plot-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z-scatter-data-in-python?rq=1).

Comment: Apparently, the 3 column should be removed (i will not get further into that). I have already tried the things you mentioned but as I said, there is always something missing. Could you please give the code to do that?

Comment: You need to post your code and the error that you're getting. Not many people will have the patience to try to blindly guess what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

So your data isn't really 3D since all the x-values are the same, but here's how I edited the example you posted. The X wants to be a list of lists, for some reason. Maybe someone else knows why.[image]

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

#step = 0.04
#maxval = 1.0
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# create supporting points in polar coordinates
#r = np.linspace(0,1.25,50)
#p = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)
#R,P = np.meshgrid(r,p)
# transform them to cartesian system
#X,Y = R*np.cos(P),R*np.sin(P)

X=[]
for i in range(0,16):
    X.append([])
    X[i].append(100)
print(X)

Y=[]
for i in range(0,8):
    Y.append(50*i)
    Y.append(50*i)
print(Y)

Z=[]
Z.append(0)
Z.append(0)
Z.append(0)
Z.append(0)
Z.append(0)
Z.append(0)
Z.append(0.84496124031007758)
Z.append(0.87209302325581395)
Z.append(0.88139534883720927)
Z.append(0.86201550387596892)
Z.append(0.87441860465116272)
Z.append(0.889922480620155)
Z.append(0.87984496124031009)
Z.append(0.89922480620155043)
Z.append(0.92015503875968996)
Z.append(0.90697674418604657)
print(Z)


#Z = ((R**2 - 1)**2)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.YlGnBu_r)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_xlabel(r'xlabel')
ax.set_ylabel(r'ylabel')
ax.set_zlabel(r'zlabel')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

A little change to the x-data will give you a surface:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

data = [[100, 0, 'TF', 0],
        [100, 0, 'DF', 0],
        [100, 50, 'TF', 0],
        [100, 50, 'DF', 0],
        [100, 100, 'TF', 0],
        [100, 100, 'DF', 0],
        [100, 150, 'TF', 0.84496124031007758],
        [100, 150, 'DF', 0.87209302325581395],
        [100, 200, 'TF', 0.88139534883720927],
        [100, 200, 'DF', 0.86201550387596892],
        [100, 250, 'TF', 0.87441860465116272],
        [100, 250, 'DF', 0.889922480620155],
        [100, 300, 'TF', 0.87984496124031009],
        [100, 300, 'DF', 0.89922480620155043],
        [100, 350, 'TF', 0.92015503875968996],
        [100, 350, 'DF', 0.90697674418604657]
        ]
x = [item[0] for item in data]
# change x here
x = np.linspace(0, 100, num = 16)
y = [item[1] for item in data]
z = [item[3] for item in data]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
_z, Z = np.meshgrid(x, z)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.YlGnBu_r)
ax.set_zlim3d(0, 1)
ax.set_xlabel(r'xlabel')
ax.set_ylabel(r'ylabel')
ax.set_zlabel(r'zlabel')
plt.show()
plt.close()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I have some concerns regarding the alteration of the x-axis values? Why should I have to do this? Apparently, the dataset above is just a sample as the real one will be much bigger. Also, I do not want user intermediation at all! the script should run for any set of data. So, how should I improve the script?

Comment: As @andy mcevoy mentioned in his answer, all of your x-axis values are the same so the graph will be a line - at least for the data you posted.  I guess I was just trying to illustrate that the x-values need to vary for the graph to look like a surface (3-d).  You can use the code for any 3-d dataset but the graph will only look like what the data is.