# creating surface data for axes3d

Tags: python, matplotlib

Okay, apologies for this question but I'm pulling my hair out here.

I have a data structure loaded in python in the form:

```
[(1,0,#),(1,1,#),(1,2,#),(1,3,#),(2,0,#),(2,1,#) ... (26,3,#)]
```

with # being a different number each time that I wish to represent on the z-axis.  You can see that x and y are always integers.

Plotting a scatter graph is simple:

```
x,y,z = zip(*data)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')
surface = ax.scatter(x, y, z)
plt.show()
```

But when it comes to surfaces, I can see two methods:

1) Call `ax.plot_trisurf()`, which should work with 1D arrays similar to `ax.scatter()` and apparently works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367558/plot-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z-scatter-data-in-python), but for me gives me an error:

```
"AttributeError: Axes3D subplot object has not attribute 'plot_trisurf'"
```

This error also appears if I use the example source code at:
http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots, suggesting it's something wrong with my installation - my Matplotlib version is 1.1.1rc,.  This error does not appear if, for example, `ax.plot_surface()` is called, nor `ax.scatter()`.

2) Use `meshgrid()` or `griddata()` in combination with `ax.plot_surface()` - in either case, after two days' of pouring over the documentation and examples, I still don't understand how to correctly use these in my case, particularly when it comes to generating the values for Z.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to call `plot_trisurf`? A update to a more recent version of matplotlib might solve the issue.

Answer (score 4):

To address your first question (1) I believe you need to import `Axes3D` from the `mplot3d` library, even if you're not directly calling it. Maybe try adding

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
```

before your main code (this line triggered a memory while reading [the tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html)).

As for (2), `X`, `Y` and `Z` need to be matrix (2d array) type objects. This can get confusing, but you may consider an example:

```
# two arrays - one for each axis
x = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)
y = np.arange(-5, 5, 0.25)

# create a mesh / matrix like object from the arrays
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# create Z values - also in a mesh like shape
Z = np.sin(np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2))

# plot!
surface = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
```

Comment: the function he tried to use, `plot_trisurf`, don't require the input to be 2D array. It should do the interpolation of x,y,z 1D arrays into a surface.

Comment: @M4rtini "meshgrid() or griddata() in combination with ax.plot_surface()" all require 2D arrays

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how could you extract your z-values from `data`

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


data = [(j,i,i**2 + j) for j in range(1,27) for i in range(4)]
print data

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
X = np.arange(0, 4, 1)
Y = np.arange(1, 27, 1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
print X.shape
print Y.shape

Z = np.array([z for _,_,z in data]).reshape(26,4)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, cmap=cm.coolwarm,
        linewidth=0, antialiased=True)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=5)

plt.xlabel('X')
plt.ylabel('Y')

plt.show()
```