# python 3D visualization from points

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, 3d, heatmap

In Python 2.7, I have a list of points in 3D, from which I would like to visualize the 3D surface using 2 things:

- 3D plot with some naive interpolation so I can see an image of what is happening;
- 2D heatmap with contour curves

I looked but could not find anything good in `matplotlib` (saw `mplot3d.Axes3D.scatter()` but I can only get it to plot points, not interpolate and draw the surface).

Did I just miss something? It sounds like such a common problem, but neither Excel or Python seem equipped for such a thing... Thank you very much.

Comment: [3D surface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367558/plot-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z-scatter-data-in-python) and [heat map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set)

Comment: @Cyber please post as an answer, i would be happy to accept it

Comment: @Cyber Could you please suggest what to do if my coordinates are not in a mesh - they are random, not a rectangular grid? Thank you