# Python - Smooth scatter plot

Tags: python, plot, scatter

I have followed the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367558/plot-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z-scatter-data-in-python) in order to smooth a 3D scatter plot I have.

My original scatter plot is,

[image: Scatter Plot]

And I would like to get a smooth plot like the following one, that was made using Mathematica,

[image: Smooth plot]

In the post I mentioned, they use the trisurf function to get a smoother plot. So I though I could use the same to get a similar plot. However, what I get is

[image: Trisurf plot]

As you can see, the triangulation did not work properly. And I don't know how to fix it.

Does anybody know a way to fix this problem? Or is there any other function I could use to smooth my scatter plot?
I think I should mention that my scatter plot is NOT a surface, it is a volume.

Thank you.

Just to clarify this, I post my codes for the original and the trisurf plot eventhough there isn't much to see.

Scatter plot:

```
S=pd.read_csv("SeparableStatesGrafica.csv",header=None,names= 
 ['P0','P1','P2','P3','P4'])
G=plt.figure().gca(projection='3d')
G.scatter(S['P1'], S['P3'], S['P0'],color='red')
G.set_xlabel("P1")
G.set_ylabel("P3")
G.set_zlabel("P0")
G.view_init(40,40)
plt.show()
```

Trisurf plot:

```
S=pd.read_csv("SeparableStatesGrafica.csv",header=None,names= 
 ['P0','P1','P2','P3','P4'])


p0=S['P0'].values
p1=S['P1'].values
p3=S['P3'].values
fig = pylab.figure(figsize=pyplot.figaspect(.96))
ax = Axes3D(fig)

ax.plot_trisurf(p1, p3, p0)
ax.set_xlabel("p1")
ax.set_ylabel("p3")
ax.set_zlabel("p0")
ax.view_init(40,40)
plt.show()
```

Comment: It might help you find an answer if you post the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky I posted my code, but I don't think I can help because it is a simple plot code.