# Plot three dataframe columns as x, y and value as contour

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot preferably a contour plot from three columns of a dataframe `df`:

```
import pandas as pd

ids =[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
lons = [3, 5, 6, 3, 7, 8]
lats = [10, 10, 10, 30, 30, 30]
ratio = [.1, .4, .2, .3, .4, .5,]

df = pd.DataFrame({'ids' : ids, 'lons' : lons, 'lats' : lats, 'ratio' : ratio})
```

How do I create a plot that uses `lons` on the x axis, `lats` on the y axis and then creates a contour plot as the example below with the corresponding values `ratio` on that location?

What I ultimately want, something like this:

[image: example]

I realize the function wants a 2D grid as input, but how would I do this considering the values are stored in a single column as well?

Comment: I do not think it is a dataframe/pandas question, more of a matplotlib question. Perhaps this could be of some help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367558/plot-a-3d-surface-from-x-y-z-scatter-data-in-python

Comment: I guessed that too but I tagged matplotlib as well, only problem is I don't want a 3D plot but a 2D one.