# Delaunay Triangulation of points from 2D surface in 3D with python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have a collection of 3D points. These points are sampled at constant levels (z=0,1,...,7). An image should make it clear:

[image: point collection]

These points are in a numpy ndarray of shape `(N, 3)` called `X`. The above plot is created using:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

X = load('points.npy')
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.plot_wireframe(X[:,0], X[:,1], X[:,2])
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], X[:,2])
plt.draw()
```

I'd like to instead triangulate only the surface of this object, and plot the surface. I do not want the convex hull of this object, however, because this loses subtle shape information I'd like to be able to inspect.

I have tried `ax.plot_trisurf(X[:,0], X[:,1], X[:,2])`, but this results in the following mess:

[image: mess]

Any help?

### Example data

Here's a snippet to generate 3D data that is representative of the problem:

```
import numpy as np
X = []
for i in range(8):
    t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,np.random.randint(30,50))
    for j in range(t.shape[0]):
        # random circular objects...
        X.append([
            (-0.05*(i-3.5)**2+1)*np.cos(t[j])+0.1*np.random.rand()-0.05,
            (-0.05*(i-3.5)**2+1)*np.sin(t[j])+0.1*np.random.rand()-0.05,
            i
        ])
X = np.array(X)
```

### Example data from original image

Here's a pastebin to the original data:

http://pastebin.com/YBZhJcsV

Here are the slices along constant z:

[image: enter no image description here]

Comment: How does it do if you call trisurf only for adjacent pairs of z-values? i.e., triangulate between z=7 and z=6, then between z=6 and z=5, etc.

Comment: That works, but the shading is off. It also adds surfaces between each z slice which is sometimes shown momentarily when interacting with the plot.

Comment: maybe you need to use one of the 3d-from-their-beginning libraries, then; mayavi?

Comment: ha. yes, I was starting to think a different tool would be the best choice. I haven't used mayavi - I'll look into it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/17367558/1461210

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16534754/1461210

Comment: It would be a good idea to post some example data here

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you could get somewhere with the traingulate only between adjacent Z-level idea and find a way to lose the triangles with constant Z.  As per the comment above - if you can add a link to some sample data it would be much easier to play and potentially help

Comment: I've updated to include a code snippet for generating representative data. I will check out these related questions, @ali_m.

Comment: This is a tough problem.  I can get a shape that gets rid of all the triangles with constant Z, but the problem is that some of the triangles with constant Z you might want (those that don't go right across the shape, but remain connect 3 adjacent points in one of your "rings".  These artefacts do occur when the triangulation is done by the inbuilt Delauney triangulation.  You could look at doing your own triangulation.  I can post an answer that shows what I can do and points out the edge cases that you will need to consider...

Comment: It's also worth noting that the Delaunay triangulation in older matplotlib might be bugged.  See here : https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/1809/.  With my version I certainly got overlapping triangles on your test data at points.

Comment: Hmm. My version is 1.4.x - not bleeding edge, but recent enough I think. I thought about producing my own triangulation, but I don't really feel like putting the time into it currently. That might change depending on how building mayavi and its dependencies goes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## update 3

Here's a concrete example of what I describe in update 2. If you don't have `mayavi` for visualization, I suggest installing it [via edm](https://assets.enthought.com/downloads/edm/) using `edm install mayavi pyqt matplotlib`.

### Toy 2D contours stacked in 3D

[image]

### Contours -> 3D surface

[image]

### Code to generate the figures

```py
from matplotlib import path as mpath
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np


def make_star(amplitude=1.0, rotation=0.0):
    """ Make a star shape
    """
    t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 6) + rotation
    star = np.zeros((12, 2))
    star[::2] = np.c_[np.cos(t), np.sin(t)]
    star[1::2] = 0.5*np.c_[np.cos(t + np.pi / 5), np.sin(t + np.pi / 5)]
    return amplitude * star

def make_stars(n_stars=51, z_diff=0.05):
    """ Make `2*n_stars-1` stars stacked in 3D
    """
    amps = np.linspace(0.25, 1, n_stars)
    amps = np.r_[amps, amps[:-1][::-1]]
    rots = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, len(amps))
    zamps = np.linspace
    stars = []
    for i, (amp, rot) in enumerate(zip(amps, rots)):
        star = make_star(amplitude=amp, rotation=rot)
        height = i*z_diff
        z = np.full(len(star), height)
        star3d = np.c_[star, z]
        stars.append(star3d)
    return stars

def polygon_to_boolean(points, xvals, yvals):
    """ Convert `points` to a boolean indicator mask
    over the specified domain
    """
    x, y = np.meshgrid(xvals, yvals)
    xy = np.c_[x.flatten(), y.flatten()]
    mask = mpath.Path(points).contains_points(xy).reshape(x.shape)
    return x, y, mask

def plot_contours(stars):
    """ Plot a list of stars in 3D
    """
    n = len(stars)

    for i, star in enumerate(stars):
        x, y, z = star.T
        mlab.plot3d(*star.T)
        #ax.plot3D(x, y, z, '-o', c=(0, 1-i/n, i/n))
        #ax.set_xlim(-1, 1)
        #ax.set_ylim(-1, 1)
    mlab.show()



if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Make and plot the 2D contours
    stars3d = make_stars()
    plot_contours(stars3d)

    xvals = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)
    yvals = np.linspace(-1, 1, 101)

    volume = np.dstack([
        polygon_to_boolean(star[:,:2], xvals, yvals)[-1]
        for star in stars3d
    ]).astype(float)

    mlab.contour3d(volume, contours=[0.5])
    mlab.show()
```

## update 2

I now do this as follows:

1. I use the fact that the paths in each z-slice are closed and simple and use `matplotlib.path` to determine points inside and outside of the contour. Using this idea, I convert the contours in each slice to a boolean-valued image, which is combined into a boolean-valued volume.
2. Next, I use [`skimage`'s `marching_cubes`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/edges/plot_marching_cubes.html) method to obtain a triangulation of the surface for visualization.

Here's an example of the method. I think the data is slightly different, but you can definitely see that the results are much cleaner, and can handle surfaces that are disconnected or have holes.

[image]

## Original answer

Ok, here's the solution I came up with. It depends heavily on my data being roughly spherical and sampled at uniformly in z I think. Some of the other comments provide more information about more robust solutions. Since my data is *roughly* spherical I triangulate the azimuth and zenith angles from the spherical coordinate transform of my data points.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.tri as mtri

X = np.load('./mydatars.npy')
# My data points are strictly positive. This doesn't work if I don't center about the origin.
X -= X.mean(axis=0)

rad = np.linalg.norm(X, axis=1)
zen = np.arccos(X[:,-1] / rad)
azi = np.arctan2(X[:,1], X[:,0])

tris = mtri.Triangulation(zen, azi)

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(X[:,0], X[:,1], X[:,2], triangles=tris.triangles, cmap=plt.cm.bone)
plt.show()
```

Using the sample data from the pastebin above, this yields:

[image: no thanks]

---

Comment: I have a very similar problem. I've thought about it a bit, and the only thing I can think of (so far - without researching) is to create a binary mask defining interior regions of your shape. In 2D, for example, compute the centroids of your triangles and pass them to the contains_points member function of the matplotlib.path.Path class. This will leave you with the triangles forming the non-convex shape. As for getting only the surface pieces... I need to think about that a bit more. But, it may be the shortest side in 2D (or least area face in 3D)... I need to flesh out all the edge cases.

Comment: "`Since my data is roughly spherical I triangulate the azimuth and zenith angles from the spherical coordinate transform of my data points.` "   Thank you for this comment. I used your method to solve a very similar problem. You saved my life sir!

Answer (score 11):

I realise that you mentioned in your question that you didn't want to use the convex hull because you might lose some shape information. I have a simple solution that works pretty well for your 'jittered spherical' example data, although it does use [`scipy.spatial.ConvexHull`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-dev/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.ConvexHull.html). I thought I would share it here anyway, just in case it's useful for others:

```
from matplotlib.tri import triangulation
from scipy.spatial import ConvexHull

# compute the convex hull of the points
cvx = ConvexHull(X)

x, y, z = X.T

# cvx.simplices contains an (nfacets, 3) array specifying the indices of
# the vertices for each simplical facet
tri = Triangulation(x, y, triangles=cvx.simplices)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.hold(True)
ax.plot_trisurf(tri, z)
ax.plot_wireframe(x, y, z, color='r')
ax.scatter(x, y, z, color='r')

plt.draw()
```

[image]

It does pretty well in this case, since your example data ends up lying on a more-or-less convex surface. Perhaps you could make some more challenging example data? A toroidal surface would be a good test case which the convex hull method would obviously fail.

Mapping an arbitrary 3D surface from a point cloud is a *really* tough problem. Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4882993/1461210) containing some links that might be helpful.

Comment: Yes, I think I may have been slightly naive when I first attempting this. I've posted more data up top from the original images. My concern is that the data is not sampled densely enough along the z-axis to do surface reconstruction. In any case, I think this looks a little beyond the scope of matplotlib at this point. I've started to look into mayavi and vtk. Your link appears helpful in this regard. Thanks.