# How to plot spherical polygons in Python using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, convex-hull, mplot3d

I have a numpy array `vertices` of shape (N,3) containing the N vertices of a spherical polygon in 3D, i.e. all these points lie on the surface of a sphere. The center and radius of the sphere is known (take the unit sphere for example). I would like to plot the spherical polygon bounded by these vertices. (Mathematically speaking, I want to plot the spherically convex hull generated by these vertices).

How can I do that using `matplotlib`? I tried `Poly3DCollection`, but this only plots the Euclidean polygon. I managed to plot the entire unit sphere using `plot_surface` like this:

```
u = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
v = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 100)
x = np.outer(np.cos(u), np.sin(v))
y = np.outer(np.sin(u), np.sin(v))
z = np.outer(np.ones(np.size(u)), np.cos(v))
ax.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride=5, cstride=5, color='y', alpha=0.1)
```

I guess one could manually calculate what points to remove from `x, y, z` and then still use `plot_surface` in order to plot the polygon. Would this be the correct way to use `matplotlib` or does it have another module, which I could use directly?

In case there is no convenient way to do this in `matplotlib`, can you recommend any other library, which does that?

Comment: `matplotlib` is pretty limited for 3D plotting, as a result I ended up doing something similar to what you have above. I found `mayavi` is better suited but ends up being a little more involved, check out the official website (http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/examples.html) and this page (http://indranilsinharoy.com/2014/03/02/plotting-algebraic-surfaces-using-mayavi/) for a sphere example.

Comment: Is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29872732/1461210) what you're looking for?